# Adding and getting another new textbox if select dropdown in HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, post, input, textbox

Current code snippets

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="Particulars">
<option value="Username">Username</option>
<option value="Email">Email</option>
<option value="Address">Address</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$selected_val = $_POST['Particulars'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
echo $selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
}
```

So for example, if i select Username, i will want another new text box to come out so I can type in value inside and submit, is there any way I can do it? Currently I am only able to echo out the value, but not a brand new text box. Sorry, english is not my first language, Thank you so much! :)

I will keep updating and showing what I've done here.

Comment: Do you want to display another textbox in the same page or do you want to display that in another one?

Comment: You will need to use JS for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use JS.

**In HTML**

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <select name="Particulars">
        <option value="Username">Username</option>
        <option value="Email">Email</option>
        <option value="Address">Address</option>
    </select>
    <!--UserName TextField-->
    <input name="username" type="text" style="display: none">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
```

**Suggested JS**

```
//jQuery
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//To show if default option Username is selected
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('select[name=Particulars]').val() == "Username"){
        $('input[name=username]').show();
    }
});

//With changing dropdownlist, if Username is selected then text field will appear.
$('select[name=Particulars]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Username"){
        $('input[name=username]').show();
    }else {
        $('input[name=username]').hide().val('');
    }
});
</script>
```

**In test.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $selected_val = $_POST['Particulars'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    echo $selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value

    if(isset($_POST['username'])){ //Added
        echo "User Nmae: " . $_POST['username'];
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you have something like below, so you could do something like this in you php code

```
// its better if you do this.
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $selected_val = $_POST['Particulars'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
        $value = $_POST['Value'];
        // and remember, if you going to use those values in a query, don't forget espace it with mysql_real_escape_string(string);
    }
?>
// if your action is the same page, just don't put (action="")
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="Particulars">
        <option value="Username">Username</option>
        <option value="Email">Email</option>
        <option value="Address">Address</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
```

Comment: Remember you can also do that with JQuery.